# Is there a way to show the selected option value in the select menu after turbolinks.visit(url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have select menu with bunch of options having "url's" as their value. Once user click on the option , it will take them to particular url. I want the selected option to be shown on select menu when taken to the particular url.

Code:
Html:

```
<div data-controller="dropdown">
<select id="abcMenu" data-action="dropdown#abc">
    <option value="/abc">A</option>
    <option value="/xyz">B</option>
    <option value="/def">C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Javscript

```
 abc(){

  var elt = document.getElementById('abcMenu');
  elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected','selected');
   var option = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
   Turbolinks.visit(option);  
 }
```

Turbolinks will take to next path whereas dropdown option gets preselected to first option. Can anyone please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location.pathname` to get the path and then set the corresponding option from the select:

```
  function selectOptionByValue(element, value){
    for(var i=0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
      if(element.options[i].value == value) {
        element.selectedIndex = i;
      }
    }
  }
```

Where element is the select element and value is the path that you want to check.

Comment: Still no luck! Its not retaining the selected option

Comment: Corresponding option will be set before page loads even though I am calling the function once after  Turbolinks.visit(option);

Comment: When you visit the new page it should run the function to grab the path and select the right option. You can add an alert in the function to see if it's getting called at the right moment.